# Minecraft BungeeCord/MySQL Server

Tags: java, mysql, plugins, minecraft

I'm developing a minecraft server with a MySQL database to handle all of players permissions (ranks, names, ect.). I'm using bungeecord to host as a proxy, and are trying to link the following plugins into databases so they are used server-wide. This way I don't have to copy-paste a bunch of configs for every single server on my network. I got LuckPerms to work with my SQL database, but my BungeeCord console fills up with this error:

```
11:34:56 [SEVERE] Wed Jun 26 11:34:56 EDT 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this with BungeeCord?

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to fix it! For anyone in the future, in the luckperms config.yml there is a properties: section. Go to it and add two lines. Should look like this

```
    properties:
      useUnicode: true
      characterEncoding: utf8
      useSSL: false
      verifyServerCertificate: false
      allowPublicKeyRetrieval: true
```